# jsp c:redirect self-referral

Tags: java, jsp, web-applications, struts, war

If you want to use `<c:redirect>` to do self-referral to the same page (with different url-parameters), 
is it possible to do this without specifying the page-name in url parameter? (thus making it easier, if you later want to rename the page)

I seems logical to me that leaving out the url parameter or leaving the tag empty (url=""), would denote self-referral.

But leaving it out gives a jasper-exception, and leaving it empty generates an incorrect url.

Anyone knows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
<c:redirect url="${pageContext.request.requestURL}"/>
```

Comment: Nice, just what I was looking for --- thanx a lot! :)